# Confusion on a lemma concerning a club of substructures of $V_\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

So i've reached this lemma in Kanamori's The higher infinite, which states:

---

> Lemma. Suppose that $\kappa$ is inaccessible and that $R \subseteq V_\kappa$. Then $\{ \alpha \lt \kappa \mid \langle V_\alpha, \in, R\cap V_\alpha\rangle \prec \langle V_\kappa, \in, R\rangle \}$ is a club in $\kappa$.

---

Now my confusion arises from the fact that the book says that the reason this set is closed is clear. But for me it isn't because given an elementary embedding for each $ \alpha_\xi $, $\xi \lt \theta \lt \kappa $, i don't know how to produce one for $\lambda = \cup_{\xi \lt \theta}
 \alpha_\xi$. Then i thought maybe he meant the elementary embeddings are the inclusion functions but that seems to be off aswell. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know that the increasing union of elementary models is elementary?

Comment: No. I haven't studied model theory that much. Can you please provide a reference or proof for this?

Comment: I don't have one off hand. But it's fairly simple to prove directly from the definition. Especially in the case of these structures which are end-extensions of each other.

Comment: The statement mentioned by Asaf follows directly from the definitions. A reference will likely say no more than that. Better if you prove it on your own.

Comment: Using Tarski's criterion this can be proved easily but then again for Tarski we need all the $j_\xi : V_{\alpha_\xi} \rightarrow V_\kappa$ to be the respectful inclusion functions. For arbitrary $j_\xi$ the end-extension property can't help because the elementary embeddings might not agree on their domains.

Comment: You're thinking **way** too hard about this.

Comment: Oh i just realized that i had mixed up the notations and definitions. Thanks.